# Select rows based on hierarchical criteria in one column

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, where-clause

I have a large employee table where I have to review their access rights based on a combination of certain profiles.

Example this very simplified version of my employee table:

| NAME | PROFILE |
| --- | --- |
| TIM | MANAGER |
| TIM | SUPERVISOR |
| TIM | WORKER |
| TOM | SUPERVISOR |
| TOM | WORKER |
| PAUL | WORKER |

Profiles are "hierarchical"; consider TIM: he has profiles "MANAGER" and
"SUPERVISOR" and "WORKER" so Tim is a "Manager" (Manager needs profiles "MANAGER+"SUPERVISOR"+"WORKER" for correct access).

For TOM: he has "SUPERVISOR" and "WORKER" so Tom is a "Supervisor"

I can make a SELECT for PROFILE = "MANAGER" for all the managers.

But how can I select for PAUL, meaning I only want names with PROFILES = "WORKER" excluding "SUPERVISOR" and "MANAGER"

I'm working in Access and my understanding for SQL is limited.

I've tried multiple statements like:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TEST
WHERE PROFILE = "WORKER" AND NOT "MANAGER" OR "EXPERT"
```

Is there a a way to pick Paul as WORKER (and likewise Tom as SUPERVISOR) with a SQL statement without transforming the table?

Thank you, Erik

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You need another table to define the hierarchy. Do not code expressions based on field values in your query.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I select for PAUL, meaning I only want names with PROFILES = "WORKER" excluding "SUPERVISOR" and "MANAGER"

You would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from test as t
where t.profile = "WORKER" and
      not exists (select 1
                  from test as t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.profile in ("MANAGER", "EXPERT")
                 );
```

Or, you can use aggregation if you only want the name:

```
select name
from test as t
group by name
having sum(iif(profile = "WORKER", 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(profile in ('MANAGER', 'EXPERT'), 1, 0)) = 0;
```

Comment: This falls apart when the hierarchy is modified.

Comment: @nicomp . . . This answers the question that the OP asked.

Comment: I agree, it does.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff for your solution, and also nicomp for your comment.